# Detect elastic scroll in Mac OS X webkit browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, macos

I want to detect the elastic scroll in order to try to replicate some iOS behaviour like refreshing my page if someone scrolls the whole page up.

Also it would be nice if I could present a message to the user just like in iOS (but this might be asking too much).

I tried searching around the web but couldn't really find any proper info. Has anyone worked around this?

P.S. Sorry for not posting code as this is still a concept. I will post it here when I pull it off.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up following a similar approach to the one followed on Hammer.js example: http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/examples/pull-to-refresh.html

Comment: Your "link only" solution is now useless because the link is died.